# “Object doesn't support this property or method” in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone have any idea why I get the error message “Object doesn't support this property or method” - which stops my site from working in IE6,7,8 - it works in every other browser!! I think the offending code is:

```
 <script language="javascript">
 function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
 var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
 return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];

}

 function stopFlash(){
    getFlashMovie("blank1").commandFlash();
    getFlashMovie("blank2").commandFlash();
    getFlashMovie("blank3").commandFlash();
```

}

```
<div id="navigation">
<a href="#" name="btn" onClick="stopFlash()"><div id="slideshow-previous"></div></a>
<a href="#" name="btn" onClick="stopFlash()"><div id="slideshow-next"></div></a>
<div id="slideshow-counter"></div>
<a href="#" name="btn" onClick="stopFlash()"><div id="slideshow-first"></div></a>
<div id="slideshow-first-tint"></div>
</div>


<script language="javascript">
if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {
    alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");
            } else {
    AC_FL_RunContent(
        'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0',
        'width', '747',
        'height', '420',
        'src', 'blank1',
        'quality', 'high',
        'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
        'align', 'middle',
        'play', 'false',
        'loop', 'true',
        'scale', 'showall',
        'wmode', 'opaque',
        'devicefont', 'false',
        'id', 'blank1',
        'bgcolor', '#ffffff',
        'name', 'blank1',
        'menu', 'true',
        'allowFullScreen', 'false',
        'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
        'movie', 'blank1',
        'salign', ''
        ); //end AC code
}
</script>
<noscript>
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"     codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="747"     height="420" id="blank1" align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
<param name="movie" value="blank1.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /><embed src="blank1.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="747" height="420" name="blank1" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Where is commandFlash() defined?

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you accessed a property or a method that doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the post with the Flash script (sorry)

Answer (score 1):

There are no elements with an `id` or `name` of `blank1` or `blank2` or `blank3`..?

**EDIT**: This function:

```
 function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
 var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
 return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];

}
```

Is really outdated, IMO and relies on some quirks mode behaviour where the ID/name of a page made it a property of `window`. I suggest just changing it to this:

```
function getFlashMovie(id) {
   return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

That should return the proper element/reference.

Comment: Thanks Meder, still getting the same problem though (at least its consistent)!

Comment: Can you make a reference like `var el = getFlashMovie('something'); alert( 'stopFlash' in el );` ? That would signify if the flash el has that property

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go, although I've just realised that this wasn't the problem breaking my site - back to the drawing board!